# Compile Opencv V3.1 failed, could not find install_name_tool

Tags: ios, opencv, install-name-tool

I try to build the opencv V3.1 for iOS, but failed: below is the screenshot:
[image]

"could not find install_name_tool please check your installation"

I download the source code and build by the following step:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/da3/tutorial_ios_install.html

i am not sure why it can't install successful , i follow the step and build V3.4 successful.

Is there anyone who can help me? Thanks.